Http PUT method is not working in OData Web API service
I have exposed a SQL Server table using Web API and OData service in C#. In my service, the Get() method is working fine, but the PUT method is not working and I get this error

System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The path template '({id})' on the action 'Put' in controller 'Persons' is not a valid OData path template. Empty segment encountered in request URL. Please make sure that a valid request URL is specified.
Source=
StackTrace:


This is my controller:
 private PersonContext db = new PersonContext();

 [EnableQuery(PageSize = 1000)]
 public IEnumerable<Persons> Get()
 {
     return db.Persons.ToList();
 }

 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
 {
     db.Dispose();
     base.Dispose(disposing);
 }

 [ODataRoute("({id})")]
 public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, Persons team)
 {
     return Updated(team);
 }

Web API config
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Persons>("Persons");

config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
     routeName: "ODataRoute",
     routePrefix: null,
     model: builder.GetEdmModel());

What could be possibly going wrong? The routing is not recognizing in the PUT method

[ODataRoute("({id})")] is not a 'valid' odata route template, make sure the combination of [ODataRoutePrerfix] (if have) and [ODataRoute] is a valid route template.
if without [ODataRoutePrefix], you should have:
[ODataRoute("Persons({id})")]
